# Are shiro and webflow incompatible?

Tags: grails

After fighting a while against this error:

```
Caused by HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
->>  102 | doCall              in org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi$_methodMissing_closure2
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|     73 | isPermitted         in sie.DbRealm
|    237 | isPermitted . . . . in org.apache.shiro.grails.RealmWrapper
|     59 | isPermitted         in org.apache.shiro.grails.RealmAdapter
|    223 | isPermitted . . . . in org.apache.shiro.authz.ModularRealmAuthorizer
|    113 | isPermitted         in org.apache.shiro.mgt.AuthorizingSecurityManager
|    158 | isPermitted . . . . in org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject
|    470 | accessControlMethod in ShiroGrailsPlugin
|    234 | doCall . . . . . .  in ShiroGrailsPlugin$_closure3$_closure24
|     15 | doCall              in sie.SecurityFilters$_closure1$_closure2$_closure3
|    189 | doFilter . . . . .  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter            in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|    449 | executeChain . . .  in org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter
|    365 | call                in org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1
|     90 | doCall . . . . . .  in org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable
|     83 | call                in     ''
|    383 | execute . . . . . . in org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject
|    362 | doFilterInternal    in org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter
|    125 | doFilter . . . . .  in org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter
|   1142 | runWorker           in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run                 in java.lang.Thread
```

I have concluded shiro and webflow are incompatible. I am using grails 2.5.0. Any advice to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I did this workaround in **ShiroSecurityFilters.groovy**

```
User.withTransaction {
    accessControl()
}
```

Hope this will fix the issue.

Cleaner solution may be to delegate `isPermitted()` method in your realm to hit the database in a service with transactional.